# LazyInitializationException when returning JSON in REST Webservice in Quarkus

Tags: json, hibernate, resteasy, jsonb, quarkus

I'm trying to build a simple application with Quarkus. Currently, I have two entity classes, which are related one-to-many:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends PanacheEntity {

    public String name;
    public LocalDate birthdate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    public List<Address> addresses; 

    public static Person findByNameFirst(String name) {
        return find("name", name).firstResult();
    }
}

@Entity
public class Address extends PanacheEntity {

    public String street;
    ...etc...

    @ManyToOne
    public Person person;
}
```

These are used by a simple REST webservice, which should store a Person to the database, select it again an return it:

```
@GET
@Path("storePerson")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public Person storePerson(
        @QueryParam("name")String name, 
        @QueryParam("birthdate")String birthdate) 
{
    LocalDate birth = LocalDate.parse(birthdate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    Person person = new Person(name, birth);
    person.persistAndFlush();
    Person p2 = Person.findByNameFirst(name);
    return p2;
}
```

When calling the webservice the first time, the result is a JSON object with the stored data, which is as expected. When called again, an internal server error is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [Person.addresses] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session
```

As I understand, the error is thrown because the transaction only lasts until the storePerson method ends, but the conversion to JSON is happening outside of the method.

How can I prevent this error? I have read about the hibernate parameter "enable_lazy_load_no_trans" but it seems it is not supported in Quakus' application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use a mapper framework such as MapStruct.

We don't recommend to directly expose your entities for 2 reasons:

- the issue you have,
- API management in the long run: you might have to change your model and not your API or the opposite.

There is an example here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-quarkus .

The Quarkus version used is a bit old but AFAICS it should still work with latest Quarkus.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the error go away by using `Hibernate.initialize(person.addresses)`, then the collection gets initialized before the transaction ends.

Comment: Did not help in my case